# Open source for online test assessment

Tags: open-source, web-apps

We want a open source tool that can be easily configured in an online server and used for online test assessments.

Most of the times it's used for performance analysis of students with multiple choice questions.

The tool should have a downloadable report (csv or excel format is recommended).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Moodle](https://moodle.org/). It has a lot of plugins: https://moodle.org/plugins/ and good support.

It certainly meets your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Go with a full course management/learning management system.

Canvas used to be available under a Free license (AGPL) but I don't know of anyone who actually runs their own instance...

Moodle is about the only player in the F/O LMS world.

Comment: Plus one for moodle, it can be a pain to configure at times, but it has tons of functionality

Answer (score 0):

Try QST Quiz/Survey/Test Online at qstonline.ca . Full featured, assessment platform. CSV export of GradeBook. Complete open source solution.

Answer (score -1):

I would say...try Oxcoder! https://www.oxcoder.net

- open source
- 500+programming tasks
- each task looks and feels like a real programming project
- solutions are automatically analyzed and scored once submitted
- report can be either viewed online or downloaded(pdf)

Disclosure: At time of answering, user was employed by Oxcoder

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with oxcoder?  If so, please disclose.

Comment: I'm working for oxcoder currently and it's really a good team. Maybe you can try it sometime and give us your advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please just update all your answers to include the fact that you are one of the team members.